# Javascript audio object not playing on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, html

I made this audio player but the codesandbox does not work in mobile devices. It works perfectly fine in desktop.

I get *`'Could not get the stack frame of error'`* error when i try to play song from my phone.

[Audio player](https://codesandbox.io/embed/audio-player-227pwf?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

The player gets audio files data in a javascript object and they get built into a list. The audios start playing when list item is clicked. The code looks like this

```js
$(function () {
  $("#time-progress").progress({ percent: 0 });
  let audio = new Audio();
  const songs = [
    {
      artist: "Yaru Makaveli & Yada Sads",
      image: "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/rI2vJENDvmY/maxresdefault.jpg",
      title: "Cypher Weyn",
      song: "cypherweyn2.mp3"
    },
    {
      artist: "Abebe Araya",
      image: "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/mp_cR7pVEcw/maxresdefault.jpg",
      title: "Natsnet",
      song: "natsnet.mp3"
    },
    {
      artist: "Shewit & Semere",
      image: "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/ucolLdVzRyg/maxresdefault.jpg",
      title: "Betey",
      song: "betey.mp3"
    },
    {
      artist: "Q Rap M.O.DB",
      image: "https://i.scdn.co/image/ab6761610000e5eb749c5e25b3d167fd3008914b",
      title: "Waero",
      song: "waero.mp3"
    },
    {
      artist: "Yaru Makaveli & Yada Sads",
      image: "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/rI2vJENDvmY/maxresdefault.jpg",
      title: "Tealime",
      song: "tealime.mp3"
    },
    {
      artist: "Eden Gebreselassie",
      image:
        "https://is4-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Music116/v4/00/4a/14/004a1407-eaed-45d3-048d-12dae76b7d3f/artwork.jpg/375x375bb.jpg",
      title: "Goblel",
      song: "goblel.mp3"
    },
    {
      artist: "Amanuel Yemane",
      image: "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/iukjMznrHcI/maxresdefault.jpg",
      title: "Adi Latni",
      song: "adilatni.mp3"
    },
    {
      artist: "Tmnit Welday",
      image: "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/MqVT5GdW6hQ/maxresdefault.jpg",
      title: "Segar",
      song: "segar.mp3"
    }
  ];

  let list_of_songs = songs
    .map(function (song, index) {
      return ` <div class="item" data-src="${song.song}"" data-title="${song.title}" data-artist="${song.artist}" data-index=${index} data-image=${song.image}>
   <img class="ui avatar image" src="${song.image}"">
    <div class="content">
        <div id="equalizer">
            <div id="bar1"></div>
            <div id="bar2"></div>
            <div id="bar3"></div>
            <div id="bar4"></div>
            </div>
        <i class="icon button-overlay circle outline"></i>
      <span class="header">${song.title}</span>
      <div class="description">${song.artist}</div>
    </div>
  </div>`;
    })
    .join("");

  let play = document.querySelector("#play");

  let currentSong = 0;
  document.getElementById("song-list").innerHTML = list_of_songs;
  audio = new Audio(`./music/${songs[0].song}`);
  let icons = document.querySelectorAll(".icon");
  $(document).on("click", ".item", function () {
    let { src, artist, title, image, index } = this.dataset;
    currentSong = Number(index);
    let list_items = document.querySelectorAll(".item");

    list_items.forEach((e) => {
      e.classList.remove("active");
    });
    this.classList.add("active");
    let newaudio = new Audio(`./music/${src}`);
    if (audio.currentTime > 0 && !audio.paused && audio.src == newaudio.src) {
      play.classList.remove("pause");
      play.classList.add("play");
      audio.pause();
      this.querySelector(".button-overlay").classList.add("play");
      this.querySelector(".button-overlay").classList.remove("pause");
    } else if (
      audio.currentTime > 0 &&
      audio.paused &&
      audio.src == newaudio.src
    ) {
      play.classList.remove("play");
      play.classList.add("pause");
      this.querySelector(".button-overlay").classList.add("pause");
      this.querySelector(".button-overlay").classList.remove("play");
      audio.play();
    } else {
      this.querySelector(".button-overlay").classList.add("pause");
      this.querySelector(".button-overlay").classList.remove("play");
      playSong(src, artist, title, image);
    }
  });

  audio.addEventListener("timeupdate", function (e) {
    let currentTime = audio.currentTime;
    let duration = audio.duration;
    let minutes = Math.floor(currentTime / 60);
    minutes = minutes >= 10 ? minutes : "0" + minutes;
    let seconds = Math.floor(currentTime % 60);
    seconds = seconds >= 10 ? seconds : "0" + seconds;
    document.querySelector("#timer").innerText = `${minutes}:${seconds}`;

    //progress
    let status = Math.floor((currentTime / duration) * 100);
    $("#time-progress").progress({ percent: status });
  });

  let artist_img = document.querySelector(".artist-image");
  let song_title = document.querySelector("#title");
  icons.forEach((icon) => {
    icon.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
      let type = e.target.dataset.type;
      let image, src, artist, title;
      var list_items = document.querySelectorAll(".item");

      switch (type) {
        case "play":
          if (audio.currentTime > 0) {
            play.classList.remove("play");
            play.classList.add("pause");
            play.dataset.type = "pause";
            audio.play();
          } else {
            currentSong = 0;

            let item = document.querySelector(".item");
            item.classList.add("active");
            item.querySelector(".icon").classList.add("pause");

            document
              .querySelector(".item")
              .querySelector(".button-overlay")
              .classList.remove("play");
            const { song, artist, title, image } = songs[0];

            playSong(song, title, artist, image);
          }
          break;
        case "pause":
          audio.pause();
          artist_img.classList.remove("rotate-image");
          e.target.classList.remove("pause");
          e.target.classList.add("play");
          e.target.dataset.type = "play";
          break;
        case "prev":
          currentSong =
            currentSong - 1 < 0 ? songs.length - 1 : currentSong - 1;
          list_items.forEach((e) => {
            e.classList.remove("active");
          });
          list_items[currentSong].classList.add("active");
          var off =
            $(".item.active").offset().top - $("#song-list").offset().top;
          $("#song-list").scrollTop(off);
          image = songs[currentSong].image;
          src = songs[currentSong].song;
          artist = songs[currentSong].artist;
          title = songs[currentSong].title;
          playSong(src, title, artist, image);

          break;
        case "next":
          currentSong =
            currentSong + 1 > songs.length - 1 ? 0 : currentSong + 1;
          list_items.forEach((e, index) => {
            e.classList.remove("active");
          });

          list_items[currentSong].classList.add("active");
          var off =
            $(".item.active").offset().top - $("#song-list").offset().top;
          $("#song-list").scrollTop(off);
          image = songs[currentSong].image;
          src = songs[currentSong].song;
          artist = songs[currentSong].artist;
          title = songs[currentSong].title;
          playSong(src, title, artist, image);
          break;
        default:
          break;
      }
    });
  });

  function playSong(src, artist, title, image) {
    document.querySelector(
      ".artist-img-bg"
    ).style.backgroundImage = `url(${image})`;
    audio.src = `./music/${src}`;
    artist_img.src = `${image}`;

    artist_img.classList.add("rotate-image");
    song_title.innerText = `${artist} - ${title}`;
    document.querySelector("#title").classList.add("song-title");
    play.classList.remove("play");
    play.classList.add("pause");
    play.dataset.type = "pause";
    audio.play();
  }
  $(document).on("click", ".button-overlay", function () {
    if (audio.currentTime > 0) {
      this.classList.remove("play");
      this.classList.add("pause");
      audio.play();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    z-index: 101;
}
.container {
    padding: 15px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(#042a45, #7295ae);
    display: flex;
    height: 100vh;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    z-index: 100;
}

.music-player {
    width: 400px;
    height: auto;
    background: linear-gradient(to top,#042a45, #7295ae);
    border-radius: 1em;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 10px;
}
#top-img-container {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 200px;
   position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
   
}
.artist-img-bg {
    filter: blur(3px);
    -webkit-filter: blur(3px);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 200px;
}
.artist-image {
    margin-top: 20px ;
    max-height: 300px;
    width: 150px;height: 150px;max-width: 300px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px 10px #154275;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 999;

}
.rotate-image {
    animation:rotate 100s infinite;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
}
@keyframes rotate {
    from {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    to {
        transform: rotate(365deg);
    }
}

.controls {
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 2em;
    margin-top: 1em;display: flex;
    justify-content:space-around;
}
.icon {
    color:aliceblue;
    font-size: 1.5em !important;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: transform .2s ease-in-out;
}
.icon:hover {
    transform: scale(1.2);
}
.song-title-container {
    position: relative;
    
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 90%;
    margin: 10px auto 0;
}

.song-title {
    margin: 10px 0 15px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-weight: 700;animation: song_title 7s infinite ease-in-out 3s;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    position: relative;
}
@keyframes song_title {
   0% {
       left:0%;
   }  49% {
    left: -100%;
    visibility: hidden;
} 50% {
    left: 200%;
    visibility: hidden;
}
51% {
    left: 100%;
    visibility: visible;
}
100% {
       visibility: visible;
       left: 0%
   }
}
#timer, #song-list .header, #song-list .description {
    color: white;
}
#playlist-title {
    color: white;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
#song-list {
    height: 200px;overflow-y: scroll;width: 95%;
    background-color: #16415f;
    border-radius: 1em;
}
#song-list .item {
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 10px;
    position: relative;
}
.item.active {
    background-color: #38596e;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 10px #07141d;
}
.list-image {
    position: relative;
    display: inline;
}

.content .icon {
    position: absolute;
    left: 20px;
    top: 20px;
    visibility: hidden;
}
.item.active .content .button-overlay {
    visibility: visible;
}
#song-list .avatar {
    width: 3em;
    height: 3em;
}
#song-list .item:hover {
    background-color: #3a5a6f;
}

#equalizer {
    position: absolute;
    right: 5px;top: 50%;transform: translateY(-50%);width: 40px;
    max-height: 20px;
    visibility: hidden;

display: flex;
justify-content: space-evenly;
}
.item.active .content #equalizer {
    visibility: visible;
}
#bar1, #bar2, #bar3, #bar4 {
    background-color: #1aa303;

    width: 2px;
}

#bar1 {
    animation: bar1 1.2s linear infinite;
}
#bar2 {
    animation: bar2 0.9s linear infinite;
}
#bar3 {
    animation: bar2 1.4s linear infinite;
}
#bar4 {
    animation: bar4 1s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes bar1 {
    0% {
        height: 5px;
      }
      50% {
        height: 10px;
      }
      100% {
        height: 5px;
      }
}@keyframes bar2 {
    0% {
        height: 10px;
      }
      50% {
        height: 5px;
      }
      100% {
        height: 10px;
      }
}
@keyframes bar3 {
    0% {
        height: 5px;
    }
    50% {
        height: 10px;
    }
    100% {
        height: 5px;
    }
}
@keyframes bar4 {
    0% {
        height: 10px;
    }
    50% {
        height:5px;
    }
    100% {
        height: 10px;
    }
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Music Player</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./main.css" />
    <link
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.4.1/semantic.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="ui-container container">
      <div class="music-player">
        <div id="top-img-container">
          <div class="artist-img-bg"></div>
          <img
            src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/1d/3a/26/1d3a2651f9ad02fb12aae08f618a2847.png"
            class="artist-image"
            alt="on and on"
          />
        </div>

        <div class="song-title-container">
          <h3 id="title"></h3>
          <div id="time-progress" class="ui tiny progress">
            <div style="min-width: 1%" class="bar"></div>
            <div id="timer" class="label">-00:00-</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="controls">
          <i data-type="prev" id="prev" class="icon backward"></i>
          <i data-type="play" id="play" class="icon play circle outline"></i>
          <i data-type="next" id="pause" class="icon forward"></i>
        </div>
        <h3 id="playlist-title">Playlist - Best of 2021</h3>
        <div id="song-list" class="ui middle aligned divided list"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.4.1/semantic.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

It works fine in desktop browsers but it does not work in mobile devices. What am I doin wrong?

Comment: It's likely the audio won't play without the user interacting with something first?

Comment: Is there a debug output from your devices? There are multiple issues that can be involved from cors, csp to unsupported formats. You need to narrow down the issue. You can debug mobile code in FF or Chrome quite well.

Comment: You cannot call `audio.play();` without the user first interacting. That's to prevent websites randomly playing sounds out of the blue.

Comment: The audios play when any list item or the play icon is clicked. It works on my computer. The problem is in mobile devices